# Condition in which DBI do method returns -1

Tags: perl, dbi

The [DBI docs](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#do) state that:

The do() method returns -1 when the number of rows is not known, not applicable, or not available.

Does this mean -1 will be returned only in case the specific row or table does not exists, or there exists some more possible reasons.

Comment: Go on and read the next sentence in the documentation as well: "This method is typically most useful for non-SELECT statements ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will return -1 where a) the affected rows are not applicable (e.g., a create, alter statement as @simbabque said does not alter any rows) b) where the driver does not know the affected rows (so it is an insert/update/delete but for some reason the driver does not know - the not available in the pod). Not all DBDs can tell you affected rows on all delete/insert/update statements, it depends on the DBD, sometimes the DB API it is using and sometimes the DBMS itself.

Don't put select statements in do method calls. Think of the return from do as "the number of affected rows" - there is usually no affect of a select statement and they are pretty pointless in a do anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It will return -1 for methods where rowcounts do not apply, like `CREATE` or `ALTER TABLE`.